# NA or "noResponse" in categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, missing-data

I am learning R and data analysis methods, so I apologise if my question is too basic. I have a data sample of 4K+ records of sociologic survey.  There are a few demographic variables and a lot of yes/no type categorical questions. There is a binary variable I am trying to predict based on the categorical questions and/or demographics.

A lot of the  categorical questions have no responses. I would like to understand what would ramifications of treating the blank fields as NA or setting them to a value of  "noResponse".

My understanding is that if the fields are NA, R will disregard them from calculations when creating a model. If I set them to "noResponse" R will use the fields in calculations and this will signify the choice by respondent not to answer.

It likely would be good to know if missingness pattern is MCAR, MAR or MNAR, but given the number of variables I don't see a way of determining this apart from guesstimate. All I know is that people didn't have to answer any of the questions apart from the binary dependent variable.